# Copia contenido de un path a otro path

Tags: java, rutas, filesystem

Saludos a todos, esta es una duda que a lo mejor me cuesta explicar bastante.

Resulta que estoy haciendo a modo de práctica un programa que hace copias de seguridad. Entonces tengo el path `source` (de donde provienen los archivos a guardar) y el path `target` (a donde van a parar).

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo esto:

  `String source="C:/origen";
  String target="C:/destino";`

Quiero copiar el contenido de esta carpeta:
`C:/origen/carpeta1/` que imaginemos que tiene un fichero llamado `documento.txt`

Necesito de alguna manera transformar `C:/origen/carpeta1/documento.txt` en `C:/destino/carpeta1/documento.txt`, cambiando únicamente el fragmento de `source` por el de `target` y manteniendo el resto de la ruta intacta.

A tener en cuenta que en mi programa primero creo la `carpeta1` y luego busca si tiene contenido. Este método tiene que ser recursivo, es decir, que se pueda aplicar en cualquier situacion, sin importar la cantidad de carpetas que contenga el path.

Aqui os dejo mi método (no es gran cosa, cualquier consejo me vendría muy bien):

```
public static void checkNewFiles(){
    if(source.listFiles().length!=target.listFiles().length){

        //Cantidad de ficheros ha variado
        //Si hay mas ficheros en la carpeta de origen copialos a la carpeta target
        if(source.listFiles().length>target.listFiles().length){

            //Copia los ficheros de más de la carpeta origen a la carpeta destino

            for(File a: source.listFiles()){

                //Crea una abstraccion del fichero con el path de la carpeta source mas el nombre del fichero
                File toCopy= new File(target.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+a.getName());
                if(a.isDirectory()){
                    toCopy.mkdir();

                    //Si la carpeta tiene contenido
                    /*
                     * CREAR MÉTODO QUE PUEDA COPIAR EL CONTENIDO DE UNA CARPETA ESPECIFICA
                     */

                    copyFolderContent(a);

                }else{

                    try {
                        toCopy.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            // Si hay mas ficheros en la carpeta destino haz esto
            for(int i=target.listFiles().length;i<source.listFiles().length;i++){

            }
        }

    }
}
```

El método a crear en cuestión sería `copyFolderContent(a)`, donde `a` es la carpeta a copiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que queres hacer es copiar todos los archivos que estan dentro de la carpeta origen.

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");

dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Shell32.Folder destinationFolder = shell.NameSpace(target);
Shell32.Folder sourceFile = shell.NameSpace(source);

foreach (var file in sourceFile.Items())
{
       destinationFolder.CopyHere(file, 4 | 16);
}
```

Saludos